# C++ attributes namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) says the *attribute-list* inside the double brackets `[[` `]]` can be identifiers.

Say I have a variable named `noreturn` in my C++ program (so it is an identifier of a variable). Does it interfere with the interpretation of the `[[noreturn]]` attribute? My thinking is, if identifiers in the *attribute-list* share the same namespace as the ordinary identifiers (in this example, they both stay in the global namespace), the compiler might interpret it as an identifier to a variable, then it won't recognize it as a valid C++ attribute.

Example:

```
int noreturn = 1;
[[ noreturn ]] void f() {
     throw "error";
}
```

The usage of `[[noreturn]]` is given here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn

**Update**: for clarification, I knew in C (not C++) there are 4 "predefined" namespaces: for labels, for tags, for struct/union members, and for ordinary identifiers. But it is defined for C (C11 6.2.3) so I wondered if C++11 has an "attribute" namespace added to them. According to the accepted answer, in C++ the rules are expressed differently but the analogy stands.

Comment: Nothing in the standard links attribute identifiers to any names defined in the program. This is the point of attributes. Identifiers that interfere with other names are called **reserved words**. Attribute names are not reserved words.

Comment: @n.m. I think you missed my point slightly.. please see the update. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes belong to a different naming space (unrelated to [`namespace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)). There is a naming space for attributes.

It is the same for labels:

```
int l=2;
l: if (l<5) { l++; goto l; };
```

is also valid (even if perhaps confusing to read).

> the compiler might interprets it as an identifier to a variable,

No, it won't!

So in your example, the compiler won't mess the attribute `noreturn` with the variable  `noreturn`, like in my example above it won't mess the label `l` with the variable `l`

See C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) §7.6.1 [dcl.attr.grammar] which further explains:

> No name lookup (3.4) is performed on any of the identifiers contained in an
>   *attribute-token*.

Of course for readability I would recommend not using attribute names as variable identifiers (but that is a hint, not a requirement).

BTW, You don't want to mix preprocessor `#define`-d symbols with attributes.

Comment: Great, thanks! I knew there are 4 "predefined" namespaces: for labels, for tags, for struct/union members, and for ordinary identifiers. But it is defined for C (C11 6.2.3) so I wondered if C++11 has an "attribute" namespace added to them. According to your answer, it seems to be the case.

Comment: C++ has a different rule (since type and `struct` tags are in the same space), but the analogy stands

Comment: > "No name lookup (3.4) is performed on any of the identifiers contained in an attribute-token."

There is a one exception though. It is "alignas" specifier which also sometimes is considered as attribute. For "alignas" argument you can provide any constant expression, including ones you defined as const.